# Qt Music streaming

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt5

I'mm trying to stream music from the internet using Qt, but this peace of code doesn't really work (and I think it should :)  ):

//////////

```
void MainWindow::play()
{
    player_ = new QMediaPlayer(this, QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback);

    player_->setMedia(QUrl("http://eteris.startfm.lt/startfm.ogg"));

    //// When I use this line, it actually works :)
    ////player_->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\\music\\Knjiga Zalbe\\01. Couvert.mp3"));
    player_->setVolume(50);

    player_->play();


}
```

And then I just call the code from main:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

w.play();
```

I've tried checking out different answers in StackOverflow, but they don't seem to be working for me as well :(  .

Anyone has any ideas? :)

EDIT: I've just tested out the code in my Ubuntu 13.10, and it works! :)  , so it's obviously a codec issue or something, after I dig it out, I'll post the final answer in here :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. For me it plays the stream, but there are significant delays.

Comment: Have you installed the needed codecs to play that format?

Comment: Great! At least it's not in the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt's Multimedia module uses the platform codecs.

You won't be able to play ogg and flac files, if you don't have codecs installed for Vorbis (Ogg is the container for Vorbis format) and FLAC.

You can find the needed codecs here:

http://www.xiph.org/dshow

Comment: Hm, I've installed that codec, it still doesn't work :( . Maybe it's because it's Win 8.1 64bit ?

Comment: Did you try getting it to work on any other platform?